# Rails 4 one-to-many relationship: find parent attribute from child parent_id attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, parent-child, one-to-many

I have five models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
  has_many :comments
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The `comment` table has the following columns: `id`, `post_id`, `user_id` and `body`.

In different views, for instance in the `show.html.erb` post view, I need to display the relevant comments with the first name of the `user` who posted the `comment`.

In other words, I am trying to retrieve `user.first_name` from `comment.user_id`.

To achieve this, I defined the following method in the `comment.rb` file:

```
def self.user_first_name
  User.find(id: '#{comment.user_id}').first_name
end
```

and then I updated the `show.html.erb` post view as follows:

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong><%= comment.user_first_name %></strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show
undefined method `user_first_name' for #<Comment:0x007fc510b67380>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong><%= comment.user_first_name %></strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I don't really understand Why I get an error related to `Posts#show`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you save the view ? :D See this `<%= comment.user_name %>` in the error. And look at the code you posted.. :p

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry for the confusion: I tried something different between the moment I started writing the question and the moment I published it. I updated the question accordingly and I confirm I still get the same error.

Comment: Well `def self.user_first_name` has to be `def user_first_name`

Comment: Instead of a special helper method, just use the association `comment.user.first_name`.

Comment: I'd suggest using `delegate`; I included the line of code in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

**comment.rb**

```
def self.user_first_name
  User.find(id: '#{comment.user_id}').first_name
end
```

with:

**comment.rb**

```
delegate :first_name, to: :user, prefix: true
```

If you do this, you can just make the same call `comment.user_first_name` and it will give you the user's first name. Add `, allow_nil: true` if you don't want it to break if the user doesn't have a first_name.

You also might want to add:

`has_many :comments`

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. `delegate :first_name, to: :user, prefix: true` definitely worked. I was feeling like there should be a better way to achieve what I wanted than what I was trying to do with the helper, and that's exactly what you suggested. It works perfectly. Thanks also for your update regarding the `has_many :comments` in the `user` model: it is already defined this way, I just posted my question too fast. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Any time, feel free to reach out if you have any further questions!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's highly appreciated.